# JavaScript/PHP Automatic check if selected

Tags: javascript, php

How can I make automatic check when i load website if in select-list there is selected stuff and color it? Here is my scripts :

```
            <select id="my-select" class="text" name="task_owner">
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_color FROM dotp_users";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                    $new = array();
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color'];
                    }
                    foreach ($users as $key=>$value){
                                echo '<option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select');

                var setBgColor = function (select) {
                  select.style.color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.color;
                };

                mySelect.onchange = function () {
                  setBgColor(this);
                };
            </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, what exact problem are you having? Also, is javascript, not Java (two completely different languages).

Comment: When i select item from drop down select-list (every name in the list has specific color). names havent been colored after selecting so i created java script that on select it colors it too. But when its selected and page refreshes it loses color

Comment: Please add that info to your question by editing it. I'm sorry to insist on this but it is not "java script", it is "javascript" all together. "java" alone refers to another language, one that would actually be and alternative to PHP.

Comment: Also, it is normal for a webpage to lose its state when you refresh it. If you want persistence over time on this you should save it somewhere (the server, localStorage on the browser, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the end of your javascript add the following code:

```
if(-1 != mySelect.selectedIndex) {
     setBgColor(mySelect);
}
```

Explenation: your PHP code sets color only for option elements. Select color is controlled by JavaScript, after "change" event on select occurs. The problem is that after page reload select is in it initial state and no change event has been triggered yet, so you need to call setBgColor function manually if something is selected.

Comment: Now website cant stop refreshing

Comment: Maby you know how to make this - i want that, when i move one select-item from select box, to another select box attributes would be the same... Coz when i move it, in second select box item loses style attribute.